# error: class, interface, or enum expected

Tags: java, mysql

/* trying to connect mysql but got an error error: class, interface, or enum expected*/

```
public class mysqlconnect{
         try
             {
            // loads com.mysql.jdbc.Driver into memory
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
              } 

        catch (ClassNotFoundException cnf) 
          {
            System.out.println("Driver could not be loaded: " + cnf);
           }
        }
```

Comment: java and javascript are entirelly different.

Comment: This is not valid, you need a method in the class (then put your code in the method).

Comment: you cannot put a statement outside a method, it needs some identifier so it can be referenced. it's impossible to call that from say a main method..

Comment: You should read Java tutorials

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of missing braces in your class.that's why compiler is not able to understand whether it is a class, enum or interface definition. so, it is throwing this error. Fix them. Further more, You can make it this way

```
public class mysqlconnect {

   static{ 
       try
         {
        // loads com.mysql.jdbc.Driver into memory
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException cnf) 
      {
        System.out.println("Driver could not be loaded: " + cnf);
       }
    }

}
```

or you need a seperate method to put the `try` and `catch` block inside it. Adding to that, you need to capitalize the class name like `MySqlConnect` to follow `Java` naming convention

Answer (score 0):

You can learn how to connect database using mysql in java using this link clearly

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-create-database.htm

**Pre-requisite :**

JDBC driver for mysql. You can download the driver from this link http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ based on your platform